# Remove Background image of textbox when text is typed. How?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have my textbox with the background image. Whenever I click on the text box, the bg image should disappear and only the text should be visible. And when the text is cleared off, bg image should appear again. How is this possible ?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"  Width="160px" ID="txt_google_search" style="padding: 6px; background: url('http://www.google.com/cse/intl/en/images/google_custom_search_watermark.gif') no-repeat scroll left center rgb(255, 255, 255);" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I tried the below in my codebehind, but it dosent work.

```
txt_google_search.Attributes.Add("onclick", "me.style.backgroundImage = none;")
```

Answer (score 0):

What it comes down to, is that that is just bad code for an OnClick event for the client side.  I would use jQuery for this, and generate something like this:

```
<style>
.bgImage {
    background: url(img/sprite.gif) no-repeat left top;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
   $("#<% Response.Write(txt_google_search.ClientId) %>").live("focus", function() { 
      $("#<% Response.Write(txt_google_search.ClientId) %>").addClass("bgImage");
  });
   $("#<% Response.Write(txt_google_search.ClientId) %>").live("blur", function() { 
      $("#<% Response.Write(txt_google_search.ClientId) %>").removeClass("bgImage");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I get this error on the function you gave, when i see via firebug : Object { error=

"Mozilla error: invalid scope variables"

}

Comment: Please verify that jQuery is being included on your page.